# Reshape multiple categorical variables to binary response variables

Tags: r, plyr, reshape, reshape2

I am trying to convert the following format:

```
mydata <- data.frame(movie = c("Titanic", "Departed"), 
                     actor1 = c("Leo", "Jack"), 
                     actor2 = c("Kate", "Leo"))

     movie actor1 actor2
1  Titanic    Leo   Kate
2 Departed   Jack    Leo
```

to binary response variables:

```
     movie Leo Kate Jack
1  Titanic   1    1    0
2 Departed   1    0    1
```

I tried the solution described in 
[Convert row data to binary columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727918/r-convert-row-data-to-binary-columns)
but I could get it to work for two variables, not three.

I would really appreciate if there is a clean way to do this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

How much spice is too much?  Here is a solution via `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mydata %>%
  gather(actor,name,starts_with("actor")) %>%
  mutate(present = 1) %>%
  select(-actor) %>%
  spread(name,present,fill = 0)

       movie Jack Kate Leo
 1 Departed    1    0   1
 2  Titanic    0    1   1
```

Answer (score 7):

One way to reshape your `data.frame` is with the `reshape2` package, using `melt` and `dcast`. For example:

```
library(reshape2)
long.mydata <- melt(mydata, id.vars = "movie")
wide.mydata <- dcast(long.mydata, movie ~ value, function(x) 1, fill = 0)
```

Pay attention to the `fun.aggregate` and `fill` parameters in `dcast`, which control what goes to fill in the interior after casting.

Answer (score 4):

Since they say variety is the spice of life, here's an approach in base R using `table`:

```
table(cbind(mydata[1], 
            actor = unlist(mydata[-1], use.names=FALSE)))
#           actor
# movie      Jack Leo Kate
#   Departed    1   1    0
#   Titanic     0   1    1
```

The above output is a `matrix` of class `table`. To get a `data.frame`, use `as.data.frame.matrix`.

```
as.data.frame.matrix(table(
  cbind(mydata[1], actor = unlist(mydata[-1], use.names=FALSE))))
#          Jack Leo Kate
# Departed    1   1    0
# Titanic     0   1    1
```

Answer (score 1):

The `reshape2`-package has also the `recast`-function.

The code:

```
library(reshape2)
recast(mydata, id.var = 'movie', movie ~ value, fun.aggregate = length)
```

The result:

```
     movie Jack Kate Leo
1 Departed    1    0   1
2  Titanic    0    1   1
```

Answer (score 1):

An updated `tidyr`-based option is to convert to long-shape, use `complete` to fill in missing combinations of movies and actors, and then just convert a logical `is.na` test to a numeric value. Then reshape back to wide.

```r
library(tidyr)

mydata %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("actor"), names_to = "acted") %>%
  complete(movie, value) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(acted = as.numeric(!is.na(acted))) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = acted)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>   movie     Jack   Leo  Kate
#>   <fct>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 Departed     1     1     0
#> 2 Titanic      0     1     1
```