# Is there an R function that can convert a existing metric into a new logical metric?

Tags: r, function, wrangle

I have a dataset derived from Pokemon statistics containing a lot of the numerical and categorical data. My end goal is to create a model or recommendation system that a user can input a list of Pokemon and the model finds similar Pokemon they may like. Currently the dataset looks something like this:

```
ID   Name    Type1    Type2   HP 
001  Bulba.. Grass    Poison  45
ect...
```

I understand the type1/type2 metric might be problematic, Is there a function that would let me create a new create/modify new columns were if a Pokemon had a particular type it would add a logical value(0 for false, 1 for true) in that new column?

I apologize for a lack luster explanation but what I want is for my dataset to look like this:

```
ID   Name    Grass  Poison Water  HP 
001  Bulba..    1      1     0    45
ect...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to one hot encode several categorical variables in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48649443/how-to-one-hot-encode-several-categorical-variables-in-r)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reshape multiple categorical variables to binary response variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18474896/reshape-multiple-categorical-variables-to-binary-response-variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tidyr is a package for data reshaping. Here, we'll use `pivot_longer()` to put it into a long format, where the type names (Type1, Type2) will reside in column "name", while the values (Grass, Poison, etc.) will reside in column "value". We 
filter out rows with `is.na(value)` because that means the pokemon did not have a second type. We create an indicator variable -- this gets a 1. Each pokemon will then have `indicator == 1` for the types it has. We drop the now extraneous "name" column, and use `pivot_wider()` to transform each unique value in `value` into its own column, which will receive `indicator`'s value  as the cell value for each row. Finally, we mutate on all numeric columns to replace missings with 0, since we know those pokemon aren't those types. 
A better solution than `mutate_if(is.numeric, ...)` would be to compute the unique values of types and use `mutate_at(vars(pokemon_types), ...`. This would not affect other numeric columns unintentionally.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
pokemon <- tibble(ID = c(1,2), Name = c("Bulbasaur", "Squirtle"),
                  Type1 = c("Grass", "Water"), 
                  Type2 = c("Poison", NA),
                  HP = c(40, 50))

pokemon %>% pivot_longer(
  starts_with("Type")
) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>% 
  mutate(indicator = 1) %>% 
  select(-name) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = indicator,
              ) %>% 

  mutate_if(is.numeric, .funs = function(x) if_else(is.na(x), 0, x))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 6
#>      ID Name         HP Grass Poison Water
#>   <dbl> <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1 Bulbasaur    40     1      1     0
#> 2     2 Squirtle     50     0      0     1
```

Comment: In your last step, you use `mutate_if` in a way that also catches HP and ID—that could become a problem since you're working on columns that you don't actually intend to change. It would probably be safer to use `mutate_at` and either select the columns you want explicitly, or select e.g. `-ID:-HP`. At that point, since you're making a numeric 0/1 from a logical condition, you can simplify the `ifelse` to something like `as.numeric(!is.na(x))`

Comment: Fair points. I covered `mutate_if()` vs `mutate_at()` in the preceding paragraph.