# How to count the presence of unique elements from each row of data set and list them in r

Tags: r

I have a dataset like the following:

```
Age      Monday Tuesday Wednesday 
6-9        a     b        
6-9        b     a        c
6-9              c        a
9-10       c     c        b
9-10       c     a        b
```

Using R, I want to get the following data set/ results (where 1 represents the presence of the element and 0 represents the absence):

```
Age        a     b        c
6-9        1     1        0
6-9        1     1        1
6-9        1     0        1
9-10       0     1        1
9-10       1     1        1
```

Comment: dummy data is what you need ?

Comment: For each observation, I need the presence or absence of each unique element.

Comment: Several related ideas here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18474896/5325862. You might need to create an ID variable in order to reshape

Answer (score 3):

This can be done by `melt` then create the freq count by `table`

```
library(reshape2)
df['New']=row.names(df)
s=melt(df,c('Age','New'))
s=as.data.frame.matrix(table(s$New,s$value))
s$Age=df$Age
s
  a b c  Age
1 1 1 0  6-9
2 1 1 1  6-9
3 1 0 1  6-9
4 0 1 2 9-10
5 1 1 1 9-10
```

Comment: @denis glad I can help :-) have a nice day

Comment: You could also achieve it with just `base R` `data.frame(df[1],
           as.data.frame.matrix(table(data.frame(1:nrow(df), stack(df[-1])[1]))))` :)

Answer (score 1):

One option with `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = -c(Age, rn)) %>%
   filter(value != '')  %>% 
   select(-name) %>%
   distinct %>%
   mutate(val = 1) %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = val, 
            values_fill = list(val = 0)) %>%
   select(-rn)
# A tibble: 5 x 4
#  Age       a     b     c
#  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 6-9       1     1     0
#2 6-9       1     1     1
#3 6-9       1     0     1
#4 9-10      0     1     1
#5 9-10      1     1     1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Age = c("6-9", "6-9", "6-9", "9-10", "9-10"), 
    Monday = c("a", "b", "", "c", "c"), Tuesday = c("b", "a", 
    "c", "c", "a"), Wednesday = c("", "c", "a", "b", "b")),
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: I am getting an error for the select(-name). Error in select(., -name) : unused argument (-name)

Comment: @fitrat try by changing `select(-name)` to `dplyr::select(-name)` could be a masking issue by `select` from some other package

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` solution, using an ID variable;

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
df <- setDT(df)

ag = function(x){if(length(x>1)){1}else{length(x)}}

df[,idx:=.I][]%>%
  melt(id.vars = c("Age","idx")) %>%
  .[,.(Age,value,idx)]%>%
  dcast(Age+idx~value,fun.aggregate = ag)%>%
  .[,-c("idx","NA")]


    Age a b c
1:  6-9 1 1 0
2:  6-9 1 1 1
3:  6-9 1 0 1
4: 9-10 0 1 1
5: 9-10 1 1 1
```

The data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "Age      Monday Tuesday Wednesday 
6-9        a     b        NA
6-9        b     a        c
6-9       NA     c        a
9-10       c     c        b
9-10       c     a        b",header = T)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. However, instead of just giving me the presence or absence of each unique element per row, it is giving me the total number of unique elements per row. It would be appreciated if you suggest me how can I just get the presence or absence of each unique element per row?

Comment: Ho, right I didn't realized, sorry. I edited my answer, but WeNYoBen anser's is way better and simpler I think.