# Row data to binary columns while preserving the number of rows

Tags: r, dataframe, crosstab

This is similar to this question [R Convert row data to binary columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727918/r-convert-row-data-to-binary-columns) but I want to preserve the number of rows.

**How can I convert the row data to binary columns while preserving the number of rows?**

*Example*

**Input**

```
myData<-data.frame(gender=c("man","women","child","women","women","women","man"),
                   age=c(22, 22, 0.33,22,22,22,111))


 myData
   gender    age
 1    man  22.00
 2  women  22.00
 3  child   0.33
 4  women  22.00
 5  women  22.00
 6  women  22.00
 7    man 111.00
```

**How to get to this intended output?**

```
   gender    age    man   women  child  
 1    man  22.00    1     0      0
 2  women  22.00    0     1      0
 3  child   0.33    0     0      1
 4  women  22.00    0     1      0
 5  women  22.00    0     1      0
 6  women  22.00    0     1      0
 7    man 111.00    1     0      0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps a slightly easier solution without reliance on another package:

`data.frame(myData, model.matrix(~gender+0, myData))`

Comment: Why does this require the `+0` otherwise `X.Intercept`?

Comment: @hhh `+0` removes the intercept and thus allows the reference category to be represented as a dummy variable. The reference category is by default the first value, i.e. `child` in your case as it is the first in the alphabetical order of `gender` categories.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `dcast` to do this

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(myData), gender + age + seq_len(nrow(myData)) ~ 
                             gender, length)[, myData := NULL][]
```

---

Or use `table` from `base R` and `cbind` with the original dataset

```
cbind(myData, as.data.frame.matrix(table(1:nrow(myData), myData$gender)))
```